# Invalid Date and Integer input in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, import, psycopg2

I am trying to import data to the database with Python psycopg2 library. First I am creating pandas dataframe. Then I create csv file from the dataframe and them I am trying to copy the csv data to the postgres. But I receive error `invalid input syntax for type date: "date" CONTEXT:  COPY table_name, line 1, column date: "date"`. Here is the code:

```
record = (('John', '2021-04-23', '450'), ('Doug', '2021-03-25', '600'))
df = DataFrame(records, columns=['name', 'date', 'minutes'])

conn = psycopg2.connect(**params_dic)

tmp_df = "./tmp.csv"
df.to_csv(tmp_df, index=False, header=True)
f = open(tmp_df, 'r')

cursor = conn.cursor()
copy_sql = """
        COPY table_name(eid,date,minutes) FROM stdin
        DELIMITER as ','
        """
cursor.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
conn.commit()
```

If I open the CSV file the data there are looking fine. I changed the date field to CHAR field and then I received this error: `invalid input syntax for integer: "minutes" CONTEXT:  COPY employee_identitahours, line 1, column minutes: "minutes"`
Any idea how I can fix thix?

Answer (score 0):

Try copy using this:

```
copy tablename from 'd:/folder/myfile.csv' delimiter ',' csv WITH NULL AS 'null';
```

In case this isn't the solution you can also find other ways to import data to the database with Python, this are the two libraries that you can use (Pandas,Pyodbc):

[How to import data to a database](https://datatofish.com/import-csv-sql-server-python/)